# How to disable checkered alpha pattern in Viewport?

Tags: interface, transparency

There are of course times when we want our renders to have transparent backgrounds. And there's a setting for that.

[image]

In 2.79 and earlier, this didn't affect the appearance of the Viewport. But now it does, in a way that is making it difficult for me to make out the grid.

[image: Checkered alpha pattern against grid in Blender 2.9]

[image: Close-up of checkered alpha pattern against grid]

Is there a way to disable this pattern in the Viewport while leaving background transparency enabled?

Comment: Hello :). You can adjust the pattern colors in preferences. E.g. make both colors the same, if that's what you have in mind.

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks! That was a helpful suggestion. The end result is what I was going for, yes. (Still accepting answers in case there is a toggle feature.)

Answer (score 1):

One option, as [Jachym Michal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/78972/jachym-michal) pointed out, is to adjust the color of the checkerboard to match the one from the background. This answer is meant to provide more detailed instructions in case somebody else wants to try this approach but doesn't find the theme settings. Please note that this will adjust the look of the transparent checkerboard pattern in all areas of Blender.

The background color for the 3D View in the default theme is `#393939` (gamma corrected). This value can be found in the theme preferences (*Edit > Preferences > Themes*) under the name *Gradient High/Off* (*3D Viewport > Theme Space > Gradient Colors*).

The color settings for the checkboard pattern can be found in *User Interface > Transparent Checkerboard* and are called *Primary Color* and *Secondary Color*. Setting both of these to `#393939` will make it indistinguishable from the regular background.

[image]